# Failed to update brew: "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge"

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to update brew but I get this error message:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
>       Library/Formula/curlpp.rb
>   Please move or remove them before you can merge.

[image: brew update error message]

The directory /Library/Formula doesn't even exist. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware of what messages said.

> Please move or remove them before you can merge.

So, let's move it.

```
mv /usr/local/Library/Formula/curlpp.rb /usr/local/Library/Formula/curlpp.rb.old
```

Then try again:

```
brew upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

They probably speak about `/usr/local/Library/Formula/`. Try this:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Library/Formula/
$ git checkout curlpp.rb
```

Last but not least check the general Homebrew status:

```
$ brew doctor
```

Comment: When I type the command "git checkout curlpp.rb" it says: "error: pathspec 'curlpp.rb' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: Did you make sure you've changed into the parent directory before? (`cd /usr/local/Library/Formula/`)